# Как в Ubuntu подключить 3 монитора к 2 Nvidia картам?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, nvidia, драйвер

Добрый день!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу подключить 3-ий монитор на Ubuntu 16.04 с родными драйверами Nvidia 3xx.

Два монитора (на одной видиокарте) распознаются и работают, а третий (вторая видиокарта) не распознается.

Карты соединены мостиком SLI.

**Сетап**:

- Acer G246HYL (1920x1080) | x3
- Nvidia GTX780 | x2
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Nvidia drivers 361.42

Понимаю, что проблема, скорее всего, с xconf, но моих знаний критически нехватает (поэтому попрошу, разжевать как дураку). Если вас это не затруднит, напишите пожалуйста требуемый конфиг для xconf.

**xorg.conf**:
Сгенерен **nvidia-xconfig**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 361.42  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-13)  Tue Mar 22 18:37:28 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

---

**nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info**

```
Number of GPUs: 2

GPU #0:
  Name      : GeForce GTX 780
  UUID      : GPU-11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 2

  Display Device 0 (TV-0):
      EDID Name             : Acer G246HYL
      Minimum HorizSync     : 31.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 75.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 180.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 530 mm
      Physical Height       : 300 mm

  Display Device 1 (TV-3):
      EDID Name             : Acer G246HYL
      Minimum HorizSync     : 31.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 75.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 180.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 530 mm
      Physical Height       : 300 mm


GPU #1:
  Name      : GeForce GTX 780
  UUID      : GPU-66666666-7777-8888-9999-000000000000
  PCI BusID : PCI:2:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 1

  Display Device 0 (TV-0):
      EDID Name             : Acer G246HYL
      Minimum HorizSync     : 31.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 75.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 180.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 530 mm
      Physical Height       : 300 mm
```

---

**lspci -k**:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
  Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
  Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX 780] (rev a1)
  Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK110 [GeForce GTX 780]
  Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX 780] (rev a1)
  Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK110 [GeForce GTX 780]
  Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```